# Concurrency with two clients of a REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

Let's assume a Spring-Based REST server application which a provides an Endpoint to checkout a list of new job object which clients of this server process.

```
@GetMapping("/jobs)
@Transactional
public void getNewJobs() {
   List<Job> newJobs = jobRepo.findJobsByState(JobState.NEW);
   newJobs.forEach(job -> {job.setState(JobState.IN_PROGRESS); jobRepo.save(job)});
}
```

*Checkout* means that while calling get a job state is set to IN_PROGRESS. Further requests to that endpoint will not return the same jobs. (Please ignore, that `GET` is maybe not the perfect choice in terms of REST)

This job handling will work as long as there is only *a single* REST client. If there could be concurrent client requests, it could occurr that a request B loads jobs and before setting them `IN_PROGRESS` another request A has done the same.

The question is how to setup the `@Transaction` properly to fullfill the requirements:

- Two requests never return the same jobs
- The server still can handle requests in parallel (which is not the case, if the transaction isolation is set to strict `SERIALIZABLE`, right?)

Ideally, I would like to lock entitites which I have read ( `jobRepo.findJobsByState(JobState.NEW)` ) for being read by another transaction B before the transaction A is finished.